# SQL Server different character, same results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm working with two queries to find some records based on characters contained in a string, but asking for two different characters i get the same results. I don't understand why. The queries are:

```
    select * from qc.qualitycuit (nolock) where fullname LIKE '%'+CHAR(208)+'%'
    select * from qc.qualitycuit (nolock) where fullname LIKE '%'+CHAR(240)+'%'
```

Where
    char(240) = ð and char(208) = Ð

i've read a few posts about the like function, but still can't find an explanation for this.

Comment: The same name has both characters.

Comment: that name contains both chars in it?

Comment: Please supply a script to reproduce the problem you claim to be having.

Comment: No, the name only has the char(208)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`char()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql) function results in the following values:

`select char(208)` = [Ð or LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH](http://graphemica.com/%C3%B0)

`select char(240)` = [ð or LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH](http://graphemica.com/%C3%B0)

These are two different cases of the same Latin letter.  The default collation is not case sensitive, so using either of these characters in a `LIKE` clause will yield the same result.

For example, in the default collation, this query results in `Equal`:

```
select
    char(208),
    char(240),
    case when char(208) = char(240) then 'Equal' else 'Not Equal' end
```

Also, the `LIKE` in following queries return the same results under a case-insensitive collation:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') is not null
    drop table #Test

create table #Test (TestVal nvarchar(20) primary key clustered)

insert into #Test
values
('1' + CHAR(208)),
('2' + CHAR(240))

select null as [1], * from #Test
where TestVal like '%' + CHAR(208) + '%' -- returns both rows

select null as [2], * from #Test
where TestVal like '%' + CHAR(240) + '%' -- returns both rows
```

If you change the collation to a case-sensitive one, the query will return one row:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') is not null
    drop table #Test

create table #Test
(TestVal nvarchar(20) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CS_AS primary key clustered)

insert into #Test
values
('1' + CHAR(208)),
('2' + CHAR(240))

select null as [1], * from #Test
where TestVal like '%' + CHAR(208) + '%' -- returns 1st row

select null as [2], * from #Test
where TestVal like '%' + CHAR(240) + '%' -- returns 2nd row
```

Note that you can browse through the collations to find which ones are case-sensitive:

```
select *
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
where description like '%case-sensitive%'
```